# Preventing Grunt from running in destination directory

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, minify, grunt-contrib-imagemin, imagemin

Currently trying to figure Grunt out and the first dependency I'm configure is *grunt-contrib-imagemin*.

My code currently looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Parse JSON
   grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  // Configure tasks
  imagemin: {
    dynamic: {
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'img/',
        src: ['**/*.{png,gif,jpg}'],
        dest: 'img/build/'
      }]
    }
  }
  });
  // Load tasks
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
  // Register tasks
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['imagemin']);
};
```

Now, this is all doing its work just fine on the first run, however, the problem appears when running it a second time. The first time it neatly minifies my images and places them in 'img/build/'. The second and any consequent times I run it, it not only minifies the files in the cwd, but also minifies those in the destination directory, creates a new 'build' folder and so forth.

Is there any way prevent Grunt from minifying the files in the destination directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your destination directory is inside your source directory. You're also looking for **all** image files within `img/` (which will find the files in `img/build`).

If you still want to keep it this way, try putting `['**/*.{png,gif,jpg}', '!build/']` as your `src`, alternatively change your destination directory.